# How do I create a Filemaker list that populates a portal on multiple files?

Tags: filemaker

I'm creating an education tracker for my boss. On one of the tables, what my boss would like me to do is create a list that allows them to just mark down whether or not the student has completed their assignment.

::Student Name::

::Homework Name:: ::Completed::

::Homework Name:: ::Incomplete::

Like so.

The catch is that there are literally hundreds of assignments to input, and as I don't want to rip my hair out of my head as I try to make unique fields for each one (and I'd like to be able to compare each student's progress on a given assignment later), I'd like to streamline the process.

I've tried to create listview where I input the assignments for a given topic and then populate that to a portal so each student can show different amounts of progress, but I'm not sure how to do that.

My boss does not want to have to select the assignment from a list. They want to just be able to go down a list of assignments and mark whether or not those assignments are done, so a dropdown list of all the assignments or something along those lines doesn't seem to be an option.

If they just wanted a list of assignments, I could created a list that could populate other fields which they could then mark as done or not, but that's not what they want.

As a note, this is how my database is set up at the moment:

---

Students----Assignments-----HomeworkList

Students::StudentIDpk = Assignments::StudentIDfk

HomeworkList::HomeworkIDpk = Assignments::HomeworkIDfk

---

And though HomeworkList has a couple sample assignments, the portal it's linked to on the Students layout remains empty

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have separate tables for students and homework which are related on a unique student ID.

You need a join table to hold your students’ homework. (Possibly also a separate table for topics if you want to separate it further.)

Your join table would stand between the student and homework table and just contain a few fields:
The foreign IDs of the student and homework tables, each related to their respective table plus any other fields you need for the actual homework event for that student. Such as Completed, Date, and so on.

You will then put a portal to this join table on the student layout.

Comment: Right on! This I have done. There is a Student table, a Homework table, and an Assignment join table for the two tables. I have placed the Assignment table on the Student layout in portal form and populated said portal with fields from the Homework table. I do not intend to use a dropdown list in the portal. The portal is empty, though I have made two sample homework entries on the homework table so I would expect them to show up in the assignment portal on each student layout the portal is in. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The assignment portal will show records only from the assignments table so you must create records there. How you do it is up to you. You can for example make a script attached to a button to populate the assignments table with the relevant homework for each student.